# In Newtonian mechanics, does the motion of an object change its weight (as opposed to mass)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, weight

> A wedge of mass $M$ is kept on a spring balance. A small block of mass $m$ can move along the frictionless incline of the wedge. What is the reading of the balance while the block slides? Ignore the recoil of the wedge.

[image]

Supposedly the weight measured is different when the body is moving on top of the ramp but this makes no sense to me. How can the internal motion of a body change its weight reading? To attempt this problem I directly did $(m+M)g  = W$ but that is wrong for some reason.

Comment: My intuition says answer should be (mcos^2theta+M) g

Comment: How did you intuitively conclude at a numerical answer?

Comment: I've done this question long time back so kind of guess

Comment: understandable, have a nice day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scales don't measure weight, they just measure whatever force is being applied to them. For example if you pushed on a scale with your hand the scale is measuring the force exerted by your hand, not necessarily the weight of your hand (unless you were just resting your hand on the scale without any other forces acting on your hand).

So to adjust the question, we should be asking **why does motion of block $m$ change the force acting on the scale as compared to if block $m$ was just sitting there?** Well, the additional force acting on the scale has to come from the interaction between the block and the wedge. When the block is sliding (let's assume no friction) the force of interaction is perpendicular to the incline and has magnitude of $mg\cos\theta$. The downward component of this force is then $(mg\cos\theta)\cdot\cos\theta=mg\cos^2\theta$, which is not $mg$ if $\theta\neq 0$ (if we are limiting $\theta$ to be between $0$ and $\pi/2$).

However, if the block is at rest on the wedge, there has to be an additional interaction between the wedge and the block that has a component along the incline. This component acting on the wedge has magnitude of $mg\sin\theta$ acting down the incline. Therefore, the downward component of this is $(mg\sin\theta)\cdot\sin\theta=mg\sin^2\theta$. And then we have the total downward interaction as $mg\cos^2\theta+mg\sin^2\theta=mg$, which is what we would expect for the mass at rest.

The figure below (drawn by a true artist) shows these interaction components acting on the wedge when the block is at rest attached to the incline. If the block is sliding then the blue interaction component along the incline would be gone.

[image]

Therefore, **the smaller force registered by the scale is due to the fact that sliding comes from a loss of interaction between the block and the wedge.** Note that this doesn't mean that the mass sliding causes the scale reading to change. It is the "incomplete" interaction that causes it. For example, if the incline was frictionless but you (not attached to the wedge) were supporting the block so it didn't slide, then the scale reading would be less despite the block not sliding.

In other words, in your scenario the lack of interaction causes both the sliding and the change in scale reading. It isn't sliding $\to$ lower scale reading.

Comment: Is this " force of interaction " mentioned in the second paragraph referring to normal force?

Comment: @Buraian Normal force as well as friction.

Comment: @Buraian In the second paragraph yes, I am only considering a normal force with no friction. But in general you will have friction and the normal force.

Comment: I'm having difficulty distinguishing the case where it is moving down the incline and stationary. What do you mean the additional interaction here " there has to be an additional interaction between the wedge and the block that has a component along the incline. "

Comment: @Buraian For example, friction. If the block is on the incline and not sliding then there needs to be some force from the wedge keeping it at rest. This would be static friction. It acts up the incline on the block and down the incline on the wedge.

Comment: I think I understand your answer now and it's a really beautiful idea. I think to make it even better, you could make a general statement regarding these things at end

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about how the reaction of normal transmits the full weight even the force vector makes an angle

Comment: @Buraian The normal force doesn't transmit the full weight. You need both the normal force and the friction force to do that.

Answer (score 1):

When an object is in freefall, it is (relative to the system) weightless. If theta is a 90 degree angle, the box will be in freefall, and the system's weight is just Mg. If theta is 0 degrees, it's a box on a flat plane and the weight is (M+m)g.

A box sliding freely on an angle is only partially in freefall. The Mg component wouldn't change, so now the question becomes "what proportion of the box's weight is applying a downward force onto the larger incline?"

Comment: I don't understand this weightlessness idea .. can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: "*what proportion of the box's weight is applying a downward force onto the larger incline?*" This is the right question to be asking. However, the sliding/partial of the block isn't necessary to explain this. The reduced scale reading can happen even if the block is at rest.

Comment: @BioPhysicist not sure how that would be the case. The reason the smaller mass doesn't contribute it's full weight to scale is because it's partially accelerating downwards, so the normal force from the larger block upwards is not $mg$. If the small block were at rest, the larger block must be providing an upward force of $mg$ to counteract gravity and therefore the total weight would be $(M+m)g$.

Comment: @BobakHashemi Check out the end of my answer for a scenario where the mass can be at rest with the scale reading being less. The sliding doesn't cause the scale reading to change. The loss of interaction does, which also causes the sliding. But the wedge / scale doesn't know the block is sliding, it just knows that its not "pulling" on it anymore.

Comment: @BioPhysicist what do you mean by "loss of interaction" and "force of interaction". Can you explain your idea with mainstream physics concepts like the normal force. I still contend that the only way the scale measures less than $(M+m)g$ is if the small mass is accelerating downwards. Otherwise the system is not moving in the up and down direction and the scale must be counteracting gravity, thus supplying a normal force of $(M+m)g$. Do you mean "instantaneously" the block doesn't need to be moving? Because that's true, but also misleading.

Comment: @BobakHashemi For example, if someone was holding the block in place on the wedge instead of the block being held up by friction, then the scale reading would still be less even though the block is not accelerating downwards. Yes, in the scenario where the block is sliding downwards the scale is registering a lighter force, but it isn't lighter because of the sliding; it is lighter due to the lack of friction.

Comment: @BioPhysicist with all due respect, I think you're throwing in some extraneous concepts that aren't necessary to understand the problem. The scale would also register lighter if the smaller mass was magnetizeable and you brought a magnet above the system, but that's a totally different mechanism. In this problem, the reason the scale measures less than $(m+M)g$ is because the center of mass of the whole system is accelerating downwards. In a frictionless system you'd measure an even lower weight than in the case with friction because the acceleration of the small mass would not be slowed.

Comment: @BobakHashemi In not throwing anything crazy in. It's true that the siding isn't necessary for the scale to read a lighter force. The reason is due to the reduced interaction between the wedge and the block. What you claim I'm "throwing in" is simply a counterexample to make my point that the sliding isn't the cause but rather a simultaneous effect.

Answer (score 1):

In Newtonian mechanics, the weight of an object (defined as the force of gravity) depends only on its position relative to a large massive object (like the earth).  The “effective weight” is given by the reading on a scale and can depend on the acceleration of the object.  An astronaut in a current space station has an effective weight of zero because both he and the station have a centripetal acceleration toward the earth. In your problem, the force of gravity acting on the block has two components. One is parallel to the slanted surface and causes the acceleration of the block down the incline, but due to the lack of friction, it is not transmitted to the wedge. The other component is perpendicular to the surface and causes the block to exert a normal force on the surface.  The vertical component of this normal force is transmitted to the scale and is interpreted as the effective weight of the block (after subtracting out the weight of the wedge).

Comment: So, a piece of gravity is not transmitted ( the parallel to ramp part?)

Comment: Or you could say that part of the gravity is used to produce the acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bigger mass and the scale act as  a system with the smaller mass and The scale should read $ (M+m{\cos^2{\theta}})g$,hence a constant value